# Filter Queryset on empty ImageField

Tags: django

I have the following class:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='books/', blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

I now want to filter the books without a picture. I tried the following:

```
Book.objects.filter(picture__isnull=True)
```

The problem is, that the picture is an empty varchar ('') in the db and not null. What to do?

Answer (score 31):

Try this:

```
Book.objects.filter(picture__exact='')
```

Answer (score 10):

Just run the ***exclude*** method:

```
Books.objects.exclude(picture='')
```